# using duplicate entries for generating multiple bibliographys

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, overleaf

I'd like to create a second bibliography for the sources of my figures using overleaf. For this I need duplicated entrys, but Overleaf gives me an error and skips duplicated entrys.
There's a `--noskipduplicates` option in the [biblatex package p.88](https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) but i dont know how to use it / where to set it.

My setup:
I use biblatex and construct the second bibliography by tagging a keyword={fig} to the entrys I want in the figure-source-bib. Then I create two bibliographys using keyword=img and notkeyword=img.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\section{Some text}
I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe. \cite{adams1995hitchhiker}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{universe}
  \caption{The Universe by \cite{adams1995hitchhiker}}
  \label{fig:Universe}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[title={Literature},notkeyword=img]
\printbibliography[title={Sources of Figures},keyword=img]

\end{document}
```

References:

```
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}

@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  keywords={img},
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I doubt `--noskipduplicates` is going to help a lot. Even if you force Biber not to error on duplicate entries, the matter of the fact still is that you cannot have two entries with the same name. Biber will just ignore one of the two, so you can get at most one of the two entries you desire.

Here is a solution that works around having to use duplicated entries. The idea is to assign image sources to categories. We can't simply filter the normal bibliography by *not*-image, because the source might also be cited normally in the text. So we additionally add all sources that were cited normally in the text to a separate category.

You just have to use `\figcite` to cite image sources in the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{image}

\newcommand*{\mycategory}{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \addtocategory{\mycategory}{\strfield{entrykey}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\figcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewcommand*{\mycategory}{image}}%
  \cite}

\defbibfilter{citedORNOTimage}{
         category=cited
  or not category=image
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title     = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author    = {Adams, D.},
  isbn      = {9781417642595},
  url       = {http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year      = {1995},
  publisher = {San Val},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Some text}
I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe. \cite{adams1995hitchhiker}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{The Universe by \figcite{adams1995hitchhiker}}
  \label{fig:Universe}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[title={Literature}, filter=citedORNOTimage]
\printbibliography[title={Sources of Figures}, category=image]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliography lists.]

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks! 
I am wondering: Should I change the Question Title to something like "Using duplicated entries for generating multiple bibliographys" Whats the standard procedure on stackexchange?

Comment: @Manuel I guess it can't hurt to change the title a bit.